# MS Access datasheet with expression at each row

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I am creating forms and reports in MS Access and need to display records from transactions table with additional field, which dynamically conditional sum previous total.

```
TRANSACTIONS
DATE         credit    debit
22-01-2015    100       0
23-01-2015    0         50
25-01-2015    0         100
26-01-2015    200       0
```

want to display above table in reports & forms as below, notice Balance field is not there in database table

```
TRANSACTIONS
DATE         credit    debit    balance
22-01-2015    100       0        100
23-01-2015    0         50       50
25-01-2015    0         100      -150
26-01-2015    200       0        50
```

actually it is query fetched from 2 tables and combined using union clause
and having not unique id. because unique_id of 1 table can cause duplication with unique_id of 2nd table

Comment: [How to create a running sum in an MS Access report](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4#bmrunningsum)

Comment: thats fine, but Actually I have a bit complex scenario that is conditional total, I have edited my question see it now

Comment: Is the balance for 26-01 $200 or $50.  If it's $200 I don't understand the process. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry its $50 I have also edited it in question

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using mysql Query as

```
SELECT 
   tbl.*, 
   (
    (select sum(debit) from q_balance where q_balance.entry_date<= tbl.entry_date)-(select sum(credit) from q_balance where q_balance.entry_date<= tbl.entry_date)
    ) AS balance
         FROM q_balance AS tbl
         ORDER BY tbl.entry_date;
```

now I have query and can create forms & reports for this query.